# Issue with setText in Java Gui JGui not numbering correctly in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, settext

Thanks for taking the time to look at another of my questions.

This seems like a basic issue but I cannot work it out.

Im working on a program which contains employees and has departments that these employees work in.

I have made a setText box which via a for loop prints out the contents of the array list which contains all the departments in the list.

I want each Department to be numbered , you know Department no 1: sales Location brazil,Department no 2: Marketing Location USA. and so on but instead it is doing this: Printing it all on the same line.

Department no: 3Department no: 2Department no: 1 Department Name: Marketing
Department Location: New York Department Name: Sales
Department Location: Boston Department Name: Accounting
Department Location: Los Angeles

The code I used was this

```
//prints a list of all employees in the system for user to choose from
for (int i = 0; i <  allDepartments.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print("Department no: ");
    departmentDetails.setText("Department no: "+(i+1)+departmentDetails.getText()+" "+ allDepartments.get(i));
    System.out.print(  allDepartments .get(i));
}
```

Could some one please help me with how to correctly code it, so that each department is numbered individually.

Comment: Your question has become slightly mangled - how do you want it to be laid out?

Comment: Department no 1: Department Name: Sales Department Locatiion:new york
Line after line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be putting any newline characters (`\n`) into your string.

You also appear to be using the contents of the text field as the department details, which is why you get the `department3 department2 department1 <details> loc1 loc2 loc3` behaviour. Each pass on the loop adds "department#" to the start of the string and "loc#" to the end. The text contents during the loop will look like this:

```
department1 <details> loc1
department2 department1 <details> loc1 loc2
department3 department2 department1 <details> loc1 loc2 loc3
```

To avoid confusion with the string appending, try using a StringBuilder in the loop and dealing with the built string afterwards:

```
StringBuilder departments = new StringBuilder();
//prints a list of all employees in the system for user to choose from
for (int i = 0; i < allDepartments.size(); i++) {
    departments.append("Department no: ");
    departments.append(i + 1);
    departments.append(" Department name: ");
    departments.append("<departmentDetails>");
    departments.append(" Location: ");
    departments.append(allDepartments.get(i));
    departments.append('\n');
}
System.out.println(departments.toString());
```

I'm using a sample string in the department name of this example as I'm not sure where you intended it to come from.

Comment: FWIW modern Javas will use a StringBuilder when doing string concatenation so it's not really necessary to use one explicitly.

Comment: But then you're doing string appending in a loop, which is a bad idea. Better to have one StringBuilder for the entire loop.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful I will use your code to better understand and to be able to fix my code.

Comment: Modern Javas use a StringBuilder when doing string concatenation; it's really not that big of a deal any more. At *most* you'd be creating a StringBuilder per iteration; object creation is fast. IMO concatenation is easier to read. Time it; not convinced it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Maybe it's just old habits from 10 years of Java, working with tight loops where it _did_ matter that the compiler was creating one StringBuffer (we didn't have StringBuilder back then!) per loop :)

Comment: Now This prints out to the console but how do I print it to a text box you know SetText when using the Java gui I gave this a try but iot did not like it very much 
 departmentDetails.setText(departments.toString);

Comment: @Spyder (I just did a quick timing and the StringBuilder was *much* faster on an older Ubuntu JDK 1.6; I sit corrected for now.)

Comment: if you're using a JTextField, those aren't multi-line. You want a JTextArea instead.

Comment: haha you Java experts, I cant say I actually know what u guys are talking about but it looks intresting. :)

Comment: You are right ,I am actually using a JTextArea not JTextField

Comment: @Spyder I think the StringBuilder optimization may happen only for single-statement concatenations; for a 10k loop appending the same string the difference is two orders of magnitude. (Fortunately I don't really ever do this in real life, I guess!)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain.. But 
Now This prints out to the console but how do I print it to a text box you know SetText when using the Java gui I gave this a try but it did not like it very much 
departmentDetails.setText(departments.toString); –

Comment: @Binyomin A standard JTextArea will display a multi-line string like the one in my example on multiple lines. What exactly are you struggling with now?

Comment: As I understand It in your code we run the for loop and then once all the data has been found and appended to the Departments we then print it in one line  
System.out.println(departments.toString());
But I dont want to print to console I wanna print to Gui  JTextArea .

Comment: @Binyomin I think you mean departmentDetails.setText(departments.toString()); - toString is a function? :)

Comment: Yes I gave you the green tick :)